# Generating representations of U(n) using Schur functions.

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, characters, unitary-matrices

We know that Schur functions $S_\lambda$ are related with irreps. of $U(n)$ and that there is an associated branching rule for the subgroup chain $U(1)\subseteq \ldots \subseteq U(n-1)\subseteq U(n)$, namely

$$S_\lambda(x_1,...,x_n)=\sum_\rho S_\rho(x_1,...,x_{n-1})x_n^{|\lambda|-|\rho|},$$
with $|\rho|$ the size of the partition $\rho$. There is a way of inverting this process? that is, having $S_\lambda(x_1,...,x_k)$ and $S_\rho(x_{k+1},...,x_{n})$ it is possible to construct a representation for $U(n)$ like
$$S_\lambda(x_1,...,x_k)S_\rho(x_{k+1},...,x_{n})=\sum_\gamma a_\gamma S_\gamma (x_1,...,x_n),$$
or any other way of lifting a $U(m)$ representation onto a $U(n)$, for $m<n$?

Comment: The Schur functions are the characters of the general linear group $GL(n)$, so if I am reading this right one could construct representations of $GL(n)$ via the answer to this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32836/recovering-representation-from-its-character but I don't know if this helps in the case of $U(n)$...

Comment: I think that _parabolic induction_ might be what you're looking for. At least for a $GL(n) \times GL(m)$ representation, the idea is that inducing straight up to $GL(n + m)$ (via the inclusion of groups that is block-diagonal) is kind of wild and not well-behaved. What you do instead is go via a _parabolic subgroup_ (of block-matrix form $\begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ 0 & * \end{pmatrix}$) and make the subgroup $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ act trivially, then induce from there to $GL(n + m)$. (This description may not be exactly right, but it is along those lines).